# Countdown on js / timestamp issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, countdowntimer

I use [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Modern-Circular-jQuery-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-Final-Countdown.html) plugin to create a counter.

And when creating, I need to add the current date in one of the following parameters (parameters are listed below in the form of a code), and the other end date and I have no idea what the third parameter is for.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.countdown').final_countdown({
        'start': 1362139200,
        'end': 1388461320,
        'now': 1387461319
    }, function() {
        // Finish Callback
    });
});
```

I realized that the time is specified in the time stamp format.
But when I try to do the following, then all the elements in the counter show zero.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.countdown').final_countdown({
        'start': +new Date,
        'end': 1388461320,
        'now': +new Date
    }, function() {
        // Finish Callback
    });
});
```

Comment: Anybody understand what deference between "start" and "now" ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `+new Date` will get you the date in milliseconds and the plugin seems to use the time in seconds.

Try this:

```
$('.countdown').final_countdown({
        'start': parseInt(new Date / 1000),
        'end': 1388461320,
        'now': parseInt(new Date / 1000)
}, function() {
        // Finish Callback
});
```

Comment: it works, but only when you use it in end too - http://prntscr.com/i46krq

Comment: @MaximZagumennyy That is because `new Date(...).getTime()` also returns the date in milliseconds.

Comment: @MaximZagumennyy I'm not sure, probably `now` is for setting the current time and `start` is used to set when to start the countdown.